# url path manipulation with substr_replace

Tags: php

With this code I am trying to manipulate the path of an url. The manipulated url does not include "://" part. It returns `httpdomain.com/string/4607120765.html` instead of `http://domain.com/string/4607120765.html`. I am looking for the php function that will correct this.

```
<?php
 $url = "http://domain.com/sfv/4607120765.html";
 $url = parse_url($url);
 $url['path'] = substr_replace($url['path'], "string", 1, 3);
 $url = implode($url);
 echo $url;
?>

http://domain.com/sfv/4607120765.html needs to be changed to http://domain.com/string/4607120765.html
```

Comment: In what case will you use :// in a URL other than the proper use at the beginning? If there is no case in which you will do that, why not just use $url = str_replace('://', '', $url);

Answer (score 0):

add one more line before `implode` like below

```
$url['scheme'] = $url['scheme']."://";
```

modified code

```
<?php
 $url = "http://domain.com/sfv/4607120765.html";
 $url = parse_url($url);
 $url['path'] = substr_replace($url['path'], "string", 1, 3);
 $url['scheme'] = $url['scheme']."://"; // add this line
 $url = implode($url);
 echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: I should have thought about it. Your suggestion is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the first and only the first occurrence of :// in a string:

```
$url = preg_replace('#://#','',$url,1);
```

I use # instead of the common / in the pattern so I won't have to escape the /. The 1 at the end means "replace only the first one."

Comment: I did not want to use regex at all here, so used parse_url, but your suggestion works. Thank you.

Comment: I see the line now where you state what you have and what you want. It is not completely clear. Do you want to change the entire path between the domain name and the file name? Sometimes there is no file name (implying something like index.html). So, that can be very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

```
/***
 * $url : url to parse
 * $replace_string : String to replace
 * $count_replace : Number of replacement 
 */
function url_path_replace($url,$replace_string,$count_replace)
 {
     //check if valid url
     if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
         throw new Exception("Invalid url.");
     }

     $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
     debug($url_parsed);
     $scheme   = isset($url_parsed['scheme']) ? $url_parsed['scheme'] . '://' : '';
     $host     = isset($url_parsed['host']) ? $url_parsed['host'] : '';
     $port     = isset($url_parsed['port']) ? ':' . $url_parsed['port'] : '';
     $user     = isset($url_parsed['user']) ? $url_parsed['user'] : '';
     $pass     = isset($url_parsed['pass']) ? ':' . $url_parsed['pass']  : '';
     $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
     $path     = isset($url_parsed['path']) ? $url_parsed['path'] : '';
     $query    = isset($url_parsed['query']) ? '?' . $url_parsed['query'] : '';
     $fragment = isset($url_parsed['fragment']) ? '#' . $url_parsed['fragment'] : '';
     if($scheme==''){
         //not a valid url
         throw new Exception("Invalid url.");
     }
     if($path!=""){
        $exploded_path = explode("/", $path);
        $exploded_path = array_filter($exploded_path);//filtering any null values

        $exploded_path = array_splice($exploded_path, $count_replace);

        $path = "/".$replace_string."/".implode($exploded_path,"/");
     }

     return "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment"; 
 }
```

in your case give

```
echo url_path_replace("http://domain.com/sfv/4607120765.html","string",1);
```

Comment: Remove this line "debug($url_parsed);" before trying.